# http request POST not returning after API call is done

Tags: .net, server, httprequest

I'm facing an issue with my .NET 4.7 web application where it doesn't receive the response from a POST request to an API I developed, despite the API functioning correctly when tested with Swagger and Postman. The API hits breakpoints and returns data as expected when debugging in Visual Studio 2022, but the web application acts as if it never received the response.

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
  {
      { "thing1", "hello" },
      { "thing2", "world" }
  };
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:777/getdata", content);
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

In API :

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("getdata")]
[Produces(typeof(ProductForListResult))]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetData(Request request)
{
    var toReturn = new ProductForListResult();
    var list = new List<data>
    {
        new()
        {
            Code = "1"
        }
    };
    toReturn.ProductForLists = list;
    return Ok(toReturn);
}
```

Possible reasons for .NET web applications not receiving API responses?

Any specific configurations in Visual Studio 2022 or .NET 4.7 that might affect this?
Would appreciate any advice on troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: Check your [W3C logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/w3c-logging) to confirm there is a 200 response for the call and that its time taken is what you'd expect.